# Informatica jobs real time jobs from web-service

Tags: web-services, informatica, informatica-powerexchange

We have requirement to load the data from web-service into the target database using Informatica. The web-service will be initiated by the source application whenever there is a change in source side. From Informatica side, we have to trigger the loading job whenever we receive the web-service instead of scheduling/batch jobs.

Please let me know if you have any option to achieve this using power exchange.

Comment: may be this can be useful :- https://marketplace.informatica.com/solutions/working_with_webservices_source_target

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of HTTP transformation to load the data from web-service.
There is a demo on this in Informatica marketplace. Download the file there to get the complete implementation steps - https://marketplace.informatica.com/solutions/mapping_web_service_using_http_transformation

And with respect to triggering the work flows adhoc, may be you can make use of file watchers. Whenever there is a web service request, you can arrange to have a file transferred to your source location that indicates a new request. I am not sure if this is possible in your case. It would be great if you could provide more details. However, there is another demo here explaining implementation of file wather to auto trigger your workflows that could help -
https://marketplace.informatica.com/solutions/mapping_email_on_non_occurrence_of_event